# Draw a pin on Canvas using HTML5

Tags: html, canvas

I need to draw a pin like: http://www.clipartbest.com/clipart-9czEGGdRi using HTML5 on a Canvas.

Here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/u5jNR/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 75;
var startAngle = .9 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 2.1 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.lineWidth = 15;
// line color
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();


var radius = 20;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

the problem I am having is I don't know how to extend the two ends.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great. What's your *question*?

Comment: What have you tried already, where are you getting stuck, where is your jsfiddle we can give feedback on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of using path commands to draw a pin.

Assume you have an object defining the pin's x,y & color:

```
var pin = { x:x, y:y, color:color };
```

Then you can draw that pin like this:

```
function drawPin(pin){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(pin.x,pin.y);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2,-10,-20,-25,0,-30);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,-25,-2,-10,0,0);
    ctx.fillStyle=pin.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,-21,3,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to increase/decrease the of the pin?

Comment: You can fiddle with the numbers in the code to adjust it to your design needs.

Comment: Works great. Thanks :))