# How to create a drop pin in fabricjs to show a location just like google maps

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to create a drop pin for my new project which is just like what we see in google maps normally i.e. A circle standing on a thin stick .
Can anybody suggest me how to draw that in FabricJS or normal html5 canvas or any other solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25043484/5703722

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a fabricjs object that looks like a pin, you have to do 2 things:

1)find a path that represent a pin

2)use it with origin: bottom-center so the position is exactly where the pin is.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
var path="M442.403,299.827c3.029,3.586,2.863,9.155-1.075,12.467v0.039l-18.944,12.31    c-12.193,8.344-64.043,17.44-134.105-68.274c-67.512-82.587-47.776-128.087-38.612-138.521l15.769-16.238c3.683-3.097,9.272-2.697,12.418,1.124l40.986,49.007c3.019,3.625,2.872,9.164-1.065,12.516v0.039l-18.387,13.092c-7.289,7.142-1.045,18.456,6.341,29.389l34.948,41.719c16.248,15.896,25.207,23.224,33.052,18.055l15.261-16.893c3.742-3.097,9.291-2.716,12.418,1.124l40.996,48.988V299.827L442.403,299.827z M557.671,215.549c0,119.02-215.559,468.685-215.559,468.685S126.563,334.569,126.563,215.549C126.563,96.48,223.102,0,342.112,0C461.171,0,557.671,96.48,557.671,215.549zM508.889,215.549c0-91.957-74.81-166.816-166.777-166.816s-166.777,74.859-166.777,166.816s74.81,166.757,166.777,166.757S508.889,307.506,508.889,215.549z";

var p = new fabric.Path(path, {originX:'center', originY:'bottom', top: 200, left: 80});
p.scale(0.2);
canvas.add(p);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, but can we replace the phone with a dot , the way it shows in google maps?

Comment: Search on icon website for a svg icon of a map pin as you like it

Comment: I found this [icon](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/map-localization_9903#term=map&page=1&position=21) to be helpful but how to get the path ?

Comment: I am stupid , sorry for asking this silly question, inspecting it was enough